# Metric for if person EVENTUALLY went to certain page

Tags: google, google-analytics

I want to know if people are EVENTUALLY going to a certain page on my website.

In my custom report, the primary dimension is keyword. Since people don't seem to be going directly to the page I want them to from search, I want to know if they ever eventually got there during their time on my website.

For example, people are searching "aviator sunglasses".I want them to be directed to my aviator sunglasses product page, but they are taken to my homepage. With Keyword as primary dimension, how can I know if the person eventually got to the aviator sunglass product page regardless if they got there directly or not from search?

Additionally, since there are multiple theoretical "aviator sunglasses" pages, I would want the page tracking to do something like PAGE TITLE -- REGEX -- "aviator".

Apologies if my terminology isn't fully correct--kind of just getting started with GA.

Answer (score 1):

I think segments provide the cleanest answer to your question: you can create a "saw an aviator sunglasses page" segment (and perhaps "did not see any aviator sunglasses page" as well) and apply it to your report. This will show you how many sessions for a particular keyword included the visitor getting to one of the pages you want them to; you can compare to all sessions and/or to the "did not see the page(s)" segment.

It does not sound like you need regular expressions to filter, if the page titles for the aviator sunglasses pages contain the word "aviator" and no other pages do. Either `matches regex` or `contains` with "aviator" in the filter input box will filter correctly if that is the case.

To build the segments, after clicking `+ Add Segment` and `+ New Segment`, you'll need the `Advanced > Conditions` panel of the segment builder. For the "saw an aviator page" segment, give it a title, and filter Sessions to Include `Page Title contains aviator`. Click `save` and it should automatically apply.

Here's a screenshot of that setup:

[image: screenshot of segment setup to include sessions in which a page with aviators in the title was seen]

To build a "did not see an aviators page" segment, the setup is almost identical but with `Exclude` in place of `Include`.

For completeness:

- If you did not care about connecting pageviews to keywords, you could use the Behavior > Site Content > All Pages report, change the primary dimension to Page Title, and filter it to aviator sunglasses pages.
- Adding a secondary dimension of Page Title to the report would tell you the total range of pages people visit when they arrive by various keywords, but you would not be able to tell whether different pageviews happened in the same session or not.